# Bootstrap Table not presenting correct in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a link to the page not show up correctly in Chrome, but all working ok in Firefox. The problem is that the textfield from the 2 columns in `<td>` is put together. In the `<th>` the 2 textfield is correct. Se : 
http://www.ofmanagement.eu/main/chromeErrorPage.asp
The code :

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<!--#include file="connectInterlineSql.asp" -->
<script src="sorttable.js"></script>
<% Set propertiesData=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") %>
<% propertiesData.open "SELECT * FROM propertiesData;",Connect,adOpenStatic,adLockOptimistic %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->   

<title>Edit Address</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-submenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="interline.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/ofMainMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   
    <link href="css/editAddress.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
<div class="topbox">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row company">
            <h3>Company Name</h3>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row user">
            <p>User Name:&nbsp;<% =session("userName") %>&nbsp;(<% =session("accessLevel") %>)</p>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row picture">
            <p>Free User Picture</p>
        </div>
     </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<!--#include file="ofNavbar.html" -->

<form name="editAddress" method="post" action="editAddress.asp">

  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container port">
      <div class="row">
          <p class="form-signin">                        
              <% if request("action")=""  then %>
                  <h2 class="text-center"> Select Company to Edit. </h2>
                  <% Set addressData=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") %>                          
                  <% Query="SELECT * FROM companyTable" %>              
                  <% addressData.Open Query,Connect,adOpenDynamic,adLockOptimistic %>
                  <p>
                <!-- <div style="height:350px;overflow-y:scroll;">-->
                 <!--<table class="table table-fixed">--> 
                 <table  class="table sortable center-block table-fixed table-condensed" id="unique_id">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                  <th class="col-xs-6">Company Name</th><th class="col-xs-6">Company Address</th>             

                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody  class="white">                
                  <% do until addressData.eof %>

                  <tr>

                   <td class="col-xs-6"><a href="EditAddress.asp?radId=<% = addressData("radId") %>&action=editItem&name=<% = addressData("name") %>&address1=<% = addressData("address1") %>">&nbsp;<% = addressData("name") %>&nbsp;</a></td><td class="col-xs-6">&nbsp;<% = addressData("address1") %>&nbsp;</td>

                  </tr>

                  <% addressData.Movenext 
                  loop %>
                  </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <!--</div>-->
                  </p>
                  </p>                  
                  <p>
                  <a href="ofMainPage.asp"><input name="" type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"></a> 
                  </p>
              <% end if %>

          </p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>        


</form>
<% propertiesData.close %>
    <% Set propertiesData = nothing %>  

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-submenu.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dropdown-submenu > a').submenupicker();
    });
    </script>
    <script language="Javascript">
function saveData(){
        if (document.editPier.newPierName.value ==""){
        alert("The field Pier Name is empty!")}                     
        else{
        document.editPier.action.value="saveItemOK";
        document.editPier.submit();     
        }       
        }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks the same to me in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: 1. Remove `display:block` from.table-fixed tr`. 2. Remove the selector and the properties `.table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th`.